# Libgdx follow mouse | projection?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make the object player follow my mouse constantly but I'm having some problems with camera projection.

```
 * Displays the Game<br>
 */
private void showGame() {


    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
    batch.setTransformMatrix(camera.view);

    batch.begin();
    bitfontBig.setColor(CurrentColor);
    // draw the highscore
    if (score < 10) {

        bitfontBig
                .draw(batch,
                        "0" + String.valueOf(score),
                        380 - (bitfontBig.getBounds("0"
                                + String.valueOf(score)).width / 2),
                        (1200 / 2)
                                + (bitfontBig.getBounds("0"
                                        + String.valueOf(score)).height / 2));
    } else {
        bitfontBig
                .draw(batch,
                        String.valueOf(score),
                        380 - (bitfontBig.getBounds(String.valueOf(score)).width / 2),
                        (1200 / 2)
                                + (bitfontBig.getBounds(String
                                        .valueOf(score)).height / 2));

    }

    // Draw the Spikes
    for (Spike spike : spikes) {
        if (bird.flyToTheLeftSide) {
            batch.draw(Texture_Spike_Left, (-30) + spike.size, spike.y);
        } else {
            batch.draw(Texture_Spike_Right, 672 - spike.size, spike.y);
        }
    }
    // Draw the Bird
    if (bird.flyToTheLeftSide) {
        CurrentFrame = BirdAnimation.getKeyFrame(statetime, true);

    } else {
        CurrentFrame = BirdAnimationRight.getKeyFrame(statetime, true);

    }
    batch.draw(CurrentFrame, bird.position.x, bird.position.y);

    batch.end();

    ////PLAYER 
    batch.begin();
    PlayerSprite.draw(batch);
    PlayerSprite.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
    batch.end();




    shaperenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
    shaperenderer.setTransformMatrix(camera.view);
    shaperenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
```

The problem is that the Player object goes up when I move the mouse down and vice versa. At the same time I think it has some delay responding.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried ti only set batch.setProjectonMatrix(camera.combined);

Answer (score 3):

libGDX internally inverts the Y-Axis, so it's pointing up, not down. Also, the origin is moved from the upper-left corner to the lower-left corner of the screen. The resulting coordinate-system is what mathematicians (and most other people) are used to. To undo the inversion, simply subtract the y-value from the height of the screen, like so:

```
PlayerSprite.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY());
```

If the player still acts weird, try only negating the y-value.

```
PlayerSprite.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX(), -Gdx.input.getY());
```

Also, i'd consider trying what Velijko suggested:

```
shaperenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

The delay in response is probably caused by the fact that you draw the Player before you update it. Therefore, the User always sees where he "was", not where he "is". Simply first update the Player, then draw it:

```
PlayerSprite.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY());
PlayerSprite.draw(batch);
```

I hope i could help =).